# Simple way to convert a "string" into a [[string]]?

Tags: lua

Is there a way to convert or create a new [[bracket style string]] based on an existing 'quote style string'?

```
s = "one\ntwo"  -- how the string was created
s2 = [[one\ntwo]]  -- what i want the new string to be
```

Comment: You mean to alter source code from one format to the other? (And, in that case, does it use only double quotes or also single quotes?)

Answer (score 2):

Escaping the escape sequence seems to achieve the desired effect, at least in this case.

```
s2 = string.gsub(s, "\n", "\\n")

> print(s2)
one\ntwo
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to make a table that has all the possible escape sequences:

```
local t = {["\a"] = [[\a]], 
           ["\b"] = [[\b]],
           ["\f"] = [[\f]], 
           ["\n"] = [[\n]], 
           ["\r"] = [[\r]], 
           ["\t"] = [[\t]], 
           ["\r"] = [[\r]], 
           ["\\"] = [[\\]], 
           ["\""] = [["]], 
           ["\'"] = [[']], 
          }
local s2 = s:gsub(".", t)
```